# Is it possible to get the email of a minecraft player with the username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to get a new IGN, but the IGN I want is occupied. Is there any way to contact the player, or is this impossible?

I've searched the mojang API, and on the internet, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I guess your best option is to use https://namemc.com/ to find the uuid and all IGNs of that user, then using Google try to find if they use the same names to play on some server or participate in some forum, and try to catch them there.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.

Getting the email address would be against several laws protecting private information, and there's no build-in way to communicate based on just a in game name.